# In GLSL (WebGL), how can I get the screen pixel X position in the fragment shader?

Tags: glsl, coordinates, webgl, fragment-shader

Initially I was using just `gl_FragCoord.x` which works great up to a point. However the range of `gl_FragCoord.xy` is between 0.5 and 1023.5, so after 1023.5 x just returns the same value.

I have a uniform with the actual canvas size.

```
    uniform vec2 resolution;

    void main(void) {
         float pixelXPos = ?
    }
```

Assuming the width is 1800, how can I get the actual pixel screen X position in the fragment shader for pixels above 1023.5?

For context, I have a single square that covers the entire canvas. I want to the shader to print a pattern on that square, so I need to know the x and y coordinate (in screen space) in order to know what to paint each pixel to.

Thanks!

Comment: @Rabbid76 are you sure? I found here that this is the range, and it seems to match what I see in the shader: https://quick-adviser.com/what-is-gl_position-in-glsl/#What_is_the_range_of_gl_FragCoord

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `highp` precision qualifiers for `pixelXPos`:

```c
highp float pixelXPos = gl_FragCoord.x;
```

The integer range for `mediump` is only guaranteed to be at least [-2e10, 2e10] ([-1024, 1024]). See [OpenGL ES Shading Language 1.00 - 4.5 Precision and Precision Qualifiers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.00.pdf#page=38&zoom=100,153,556).

Comment: ahhh nice, I would never guess that - thank you!